# How do I restrict the number of clients that a user can add in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback

Basically what I want to happen is, that each user ('designer') can only add the number of clients that are restricted by their plan. So if their plan only allows 1 client, that's all they can do.

My user model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable

  has_many :clients,
           :through => :client_ownerships,
           :order => 'created_at DESC'

{edited for brevity}

end
```

The client model looks like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :number_of_clients  
    belongs_to :user

  has_many :projects, :order => 'created_at DESC', :dependent => :destroy

  has_one :ownership, :dependent => :destroy

  has_one :designer, :through => :ownership
  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length => {:minimum => 1, :maximum => 128}

  def number_of_clients
     Authorization.current_user.clients.count < Authorization.current_user.plan.num_of_clients    
  end

end
```

The plan model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110214082231
#
# Table name: plans
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  storage         :float
#  num_of_projects :integer
#  num_of_clients  :integer
#  cached_slug     :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#  price           :integer
#

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having your `number_of_clients` method be called with a `before_save` callback, use a validation callback instead:

```
# app/models/client.rb
validate :is_within_plan_limits

def is_within_plan_limits
   errors.add(:client, 'You cannot add another client') if user.max_clients?
end

# app/models/user.rb
def max_clients?
  Authorization.current_user.clients.count > Authorization.current_user.plan.num_of_clients
end

# app/controllers/client_controller.rb
def new
  redirect_to(some_path, :notice => 'Time to upgrade') and return if current_user.max_clients?
end
```

See the docs on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods).

You can check the number of clients in your controller new action to make sure that the user has a free client slot, and direct them to upgrade if not. This validation would simply enforce this UI.

Comment: Would that be on the client model ?

Comment: Yes. You would want the Client model to restrict the number of Clients that exist for the user, rather than concerning your User model with how many Clients there are.

Comment: This works nicely. But in my logs, I see this: `NoMethodError (undefined method `You cannot add another client' for #<Client:0x000001059b1030>):
  app/models/client.rb:34:in `number_of_clients'
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:8:in `create'
` Why does it say 'undefined method' ?

Comment: Also, could you give an example of how that check in the controller would look? Isn't it best to do all those sorts of checks in the model - i.e. fat models, skinny controllers ?

Comment: Updated. I'm using some more generic code regarding the users (more Authlogic style), but I think it should be more clear to you now.

Comment: Hrmm...don't you mean `validate :is_within_plan_limits` in the client.rb ?

Comment: Btw, we are getting there...but now I am getting the following error for the controller: `NoMethodError (undefined method max_clients?' for #<User:0x00000100aead20>):
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:8:in create'` 

Thoughts ?

Comment: @marcamillion 1) Yes. Fixed. 2) Did you define the `max_clients?` method on your User model?

Comment: Yep...followed your instructions to the T. Even re-did it and still getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'max_clients?' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/client.rb:39:in 'is_within_plan_limits'
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:13:in 'create'`

Comment: Want me to paste the entire models and controller somewhere ?

Comment: If you throw them in a gist (http://gist.github.com/) and post the link I'll check it out.

Comment: It looks like you've added the code I wrote exactly, and that's the problem. You need to adjust it to work within the relationships you have going on. You're calling `current_user` from within yoqur user model, which would return that same user. Adjust the code to work within the relationships you have defined. Also, it appears that `current_user` isn't how you access the active user session in Devise, so that local variable is `nil`, hence the NoMethodError on `nil:NillClass`. You will need to replace `current_user` in the controller with an instance of the User you are testing against.

Comment: Ok...will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add custom validation to the attribute?

Something like:

```
validate_on_create :within_client_limit

def within_client_limit
  errors.add("Client limit exceeded") if client.length > current_user.plan.client_limit
end
```

Comment: Nick...where would I add that ? Given my models...would that be on the user model or client model ? I do like where you are going though. Also, why would you do `client.length` and not `current_user.num_of_clients.count` ?

Comment: Ok sorry-  the validation would go in the User model because it's the length of the user's list of clients that you're trying to limit. So you're getting the length (number) of clients held by the user and saying that it's not valid if it goes over the limit.  Also client_limit should be num_of_clients  for your setup.